# Author names are strangely attached to the citations

Tags: bibtex

In the following file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The authors \cite{Berliant2004Foundation,Caragiannis2011Towards} 
    study specific non-additive value functions.

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{./mwe}
\end{document}
```

With the following mwe.bib file:

```
@article{Berliant2004Foundation,
  author =        {Berliant, Marcus and Dunz, Karl},
  journal =       {Journal of Mathematical Economics},
  title =         {{A foundation of location theory: existence of equilibrium, the welfare theorems, and core}},
  year =          {2004},
}
@inproceedings{Caragiannis2011Towards,
  author =        {Caragiannis, Ioannis and Lai, John K. and Procaccia, Ariel D.},
  booktitle =     {Proceedings of the 22nd International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence (IJCAI-11)},
  title =         {{Towards more expressive cake cutting}},
  year =          {2011},
}
```

The output is:

> The authors [Berliant and Dunz(2004), **Caragiannis et
>   al(2011)Caragiannis, Lai, and Procaccia**] study specific non-additive value functions.

The first reference is OK, but in the second reference, the names of all authors are added after the year. How to prevent this?

Comment: The `spbasic` style requires `\usepackage{natbib}` in the preamble.

Comment: The problem is solved after adding "\usepackage{natbib}". It is strange that this is not mentioned in their template file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bibliography style `spbasic` requires `\usepackage{natbib}` as it's seen in the comments on top of it

```
%%********************************************************************************%%
%%                                                                                %%
%% For Springer medical, life sciences, chemistry, geology, engineering and       %%
%%   computer science publications.                                               %%
%% For use with the natbib package (see below). Default is author-year citations. %%
%%   When citations are numbered, please use \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}.        %%
%% A lack of punctuation is the key feature. Springer-Verlag 2004/10/15           %%
%% Report bugs and improvements to: Joylene Vette-Guillaume or Frank Holzwarth    %%
%%                                                                                %%
%%********************************************************************************%%
```

Springer class files might already load `natbib`; if you use a standard class you have to add the call yourself.

Comment: To help future readers of this answer:    if adding "usepackage{natbib}" does not help, try to remove the temporary files and re-create them.